# getting a problem where the radio button selections are getting reset to the first radio option

Tags: html, web-development-server

I am a beigner.And i dont know why the gender radio input is getting reset when i click anywhere on the screen below the rdio buttons section.Can anyone help me with this.This below is my code⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Sign Up Form</h2>
    <br><br>
    <form method=GET action="./pages mine/thank you.html">
        <input type="text" placeholder="First name"><br><br>
        
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last name"><br><br>
    
        <input type="email" placeholder="Last name"><br><br>
    
        <input type="password" placeholder="Last name" minlength="5"><br><br>
<!--gender selection-->
        <label><h3>Select Gender<h3></label><br>
        
        <label for="male">male</label>
        <input type="radio"  value="male" id="male" name="gender" required/><br>
        
        <label for="female">female</label>
        <input type="radio" value="female" id="female" name="gender" required/><br>
        
        <label for="other">other</label>
        <input type="radio" value="other" id="other" name="gender"  required/><br><br>
<!--when i click on the screen anywhr after this the gender selection is getting reset-->        
        <label for="nation">Country</label>
        <select id="nation" >
            
            <option value="india" name="nation">INDIA</option>
            <option value="usa" name="nation">USA</option>
            <option value="other" name="nation">OTHER</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <p>Write about yourself below</p><br>
        <input type="textbox" placeholder="type here"><br>
        <input type="submit" placeholder="Sign in">
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

i was trying the make radio buttons for gender selection but the selection is getting reset on click any where on the screen after the radio buttons section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of things going wrong in this code.

But for your radio button issue, i think this is caused by `<label><h3>Select Gender<h3></label><br>`. Your `<h3>`node is not closed. It should be :

`<h3>Select Gender</h3>`

Also you don't need a `label`around that.

Here is a refactored version of your code :

https://jsfiddle.net/dzt8ja6n/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Sign Up Form</h2>
    <br><br>
    <form method="GET" action="./pages mine/thank you.html">
        <input type="text" placeholder="First name"><br><br>
        
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last name"><br><br>
    
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email"><br><br>
    
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" minlength="5"><br><br>

        <!-- Gender selection -->
        <label for="gender"><h3>Select Gender</h3></label><br>
        
        <label for="male">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" value="male" id="male" name="gender" required><br>
        
        <label for="female">Female</label>
        <input type="radio" value="female" id="female" name="gender" required><br>
        
        <label for="other">Other</label>
        <input type="radio" value="other" id="other" name="gender" required><br><br>
        
        <label for="nation">Country</label>
        <select id="nation" name="nation">
            <option value="india">INDIA</option>
            <option value="usa">USA</option>
            <option value="other">OTHER</option>
        </select><br><br>
        
        <p>Write about yourself below</p><br>
        <textarea placeholder="Type here"></textarea><br>
        
        <input type="submit" value="Sign in">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you that cleared the issue ....placeholders ,I did notice that i hadn't changed em after copying.

Comment: I'll let you find the 7 differences ;) Also be carreful with spaces in your filenames. It is usually better to avoid spaces (transfers issues) `./pages_mine/thank_you.html`